# Can I direct nightmare.js to go to my express route on localhost?

Tags: node.js, express, nightmare

I have a function that fires whenever someone hits my `/data` route. I want to hit it myself with a headless browser instance. Or is my thought process just out to lunch?

```
nightmare.goto('http://localhost:3000/data')
.then(() => {
  console.log('did it work?');
})


app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
  myfunction();
})
```

Getting: **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: navigation error**
so clearly it doesn't like that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the server before you try to reach it from nightmareJS. So,

```
app.listen(3000, function(){
  nightmare.goto('http://localhost:3000/data')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('did it work?');
  })
})
```

Really bad example, but that's what you are looking for. Hope it works.